# Error: Specified Cast is not valid when joining 3 tables

Tags: sql

Error: Specified Cast is not valid. This occurs on Inner Join Codes

```
string Query = "SELECT User.First, User.Last, Details.Address1, 
                       Details.Address2, Details.County, Details.Country, Code.Codenum  
                FROM User INNER JOIN Details on User.Details_DetailsID = Details.DetailsID 
                      INNER JOIN Codes on User.Code_ID = Code.ID 
                WHERE User.Last ='" + cbUsers.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";



 string snum = myReader.GetInt32(1).ToString();
 txtcode.Text = snum;
```

Comment: What RDBMS? Does your query work with `User.Code.ID`?

Answer (score 0):

`GetInt32(1)` mean that you get the second column value from your reader which is named as `User.Last`. I think it is last name which, probably, can't be converted to `Int32`.